# How to determine what script is deleting files in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management, cron, auditd

I run a Plex Media Server (PMS) on a ubuntu 22.04 system.  There's been no update to the PMS libraries for a while, and I recently started adding a few movies to the collection.  But what I've found is that within a few hours of adding a directory/file, it gets deleted from the system without a trace.  It doesn't seem to be moved or archived - just deleted.

The parent directory in question is /svr/PlexMedia/Movies.  For example, I recently added these, and they disappeared within a couple of hours.  I have since re-added them:

```
> find /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Makin* -ls                                        
195952644      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 dennis   dennis       4096 Nov 30 05:10 /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making\ Dark\ Side\ of\ the\ Moon\ (2002)
201326598 5449764 -rw-rw-r--   2 dennis   dennis   5580551395 Nov 29 12:43 /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making\ Dark\ Side\ of\ the\ Moon\ (2002)/Making\ Dark\ Side\ of\ the\ Moon\ (2002).mp4
```

Because of this problem, I created the following PHP script to watch the folder

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// Watch for new media in the specified folder

define('REPORT_WATCH_COUNT', 0x00000001) ;
define('DONT_REPORT_WATCH_COUNT', 0x000000) ;

require_once('lovefunctions.php') ;
$lov->setLogName(LoveFunctions::MONTHLY_LOG_WITH_HEADER) ;
    
$topFolder = $argv[1] ;

$lov->setLogName(loveFunctions::MONTHLY_LOG) ;

$watchList = inotify_init();
$watchedFolders = [] ;
    
$watchMask = IN_CREATE | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_DELETE | IN_DELETE_SELF ;

$lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Starting %s.  Top directory is %s, watch mask is %08x', basename($lov->pageFile()), $topFolder, $watchMask ] ) ;
    
addWatch($watchList, $topFolder) ;

// We'll watch our own script file... if our file changes, then we'll resubmit and end - old script is not viable anymore.

$watchMe = inotify_add_watch($watchList, $lov->pageFile(), IN_CREATE | IN_CLOSE_WRITE) ;
$watchedFolders[$watchMe] = [ 'path' => $lov->pageFile() ] ;
$lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Watching for changes to this script (%s).  Watch ID is %d.', $lov->pageFile(), $watchMe ] ) ;
watchLoop($watchList, $watchMe, $watchMask) ;

array_reverse($watchedFolders) ;
foreach ($watchedFolders as $watchId => $watchItem) {
    inotify_rm_watch($watchList, $watchId) ;
}
fclose($watchList);

function addWatch($watchList, string $folderName, int $flags = REPORT_WATCH_COUNT) {
    global $lov, $watchedFolders, $watchMask ;

    if (is_dir($folderName)) {
        if (substr($folderName, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) $folderName .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
        $watchId = inotify_add_watch($watchList, $folderName, $watchMask) ;
        if ($watchId) {
            $watchedFolders[$watchId] = [ 'path' => $folderName
                                        , 'events' => 0
                                            ] ;
            $files = scandir($folderName) ;
            $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Added %s to the watch list (id=%d).', $folderName, $watchId ] ) ;
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
                    continue ;
                $file = $folderName . $file ;
                if (is_dir($file))
                    addWatch($watchList, $file, DONT_REPORT_WATCH_COUNT) ;
            }
        }
    }
    if (($flags & REPORT_WATCH_COUNT) == REPORT_WATCH_COUNT)
        reportCount(count($watchedFolders) - 1) ;
    return ;
}


function removeWatch($watchList, $watchId, int $flags = REPORT_WATCH_COUNT, int $mask = 0) {
    global $lov, $watchedFolders ;

    if (isset($watchedFolders[$watchId])) {
        $watch = $watchedFolders[$watchId] ;
        if ($watch['events'] > 0)
            $msg = sprintf('Removing watch %d (folder %s) after %d events triggered.', $watchId, $watch['path'], $watch['events']) ;
        else
            $msg = sprintf('Removing unused watch %d (folder %s)', $watchId, $watch['path']) ;
        $lov->writeLogLine( $msg ) ;
        unset($watchedFolders[$watchId]) ;
        if (($mask & IN_DELETE_SELF) != IN_DELETE_SELF) // Seems the system already removes this for us
            inotify_rm_watch($watchList, $watchId) ;
    }
    if (($flags & REPORT_WATCH_COUNT) == REPORT_WATCH_COUNT)
        reportCount(count($watchedFolders) - 1) ;
}


function reportCount($count) {
    global $lov ;

    $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'There %s now %d folder%s in the watch list (plus the self-monitor)', $count == 1 ? 'is' : 'are', $count, $count == 1 ? '' : 's' ] ) ;
}


function checkSyntax(string $scriptName) : bool {
    global $lov ;

    $output = [] ;
    $rc = -1 ;
    $cmd = sprintf('php -l %s 2>&1', escapeshellarg($scriptName)) ;
    exec($cmd, $output, $rc) ;
    if ($rc != 0) // Not successful
        return false ;
    foreach ($output AS $line) {
        if (preg_match('%^(.*error: |Errors parsing )%', $line))
            return false ; // Syntax error or other error
    }
    return true ;
}




function watchLoop($watchList, int $watchMe, int $watchMask) {
    global $lov, $watchedFolders , $pdo, $topFolder ;

    $floodStart = null ;
    while (true) {
        $mtimeStart = microtime(true) ;
        $events = inotify_read($watchList);
        $mtimeEnd = microtime(true) ;
        if (! $events) {
            $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Something is seriously wrong!  inotify_read returned false/null/empty response.  Giving up.' ] ) ;
            return false ;
        }
        if (($elapsed = ($mtimeEnd - $mtimeStart)) < 1) { // Less than a second since prior - may not be a problem, but let's watch closely...
            if (is_null($floodStart)) {
                $floodStart = $mtimeStart ;
                $floodCount = count($events) ;
            } else {
                $floodCount += count($events) ;
                if ($floodCount > 100) { // More than one hundred events, all within a second of each other.  We seem to be looping.
                    $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'In %.3f seconds, there have been %d events.  Too much too fast.  Giving up.', microtime() - $floodStart, $floodCount ] ) ;
                }
            }
        } else { // Elapsed > 1 second.  This is normal.
            $floodStart = null ; // Call off the dogs
        }
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $mask = $event['mask'] ;
            $watchId = $event['wd'] ;
            if ( ! array_key_exists($watchId, $watchedFolders)) {
                $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Received event %08x for watch ID %d but watchId is not in our watchedFolders array.', $mask, $watchId ] ) ;
                continue ;
            }
            $watch = &$watchedFolders[$watchId] ;
            if (is_null($watch)) {
                $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Wanted to access $watchedFolders[%d] but it\'s null.  Removing it.', $watchId ] ) ;
                unset($watchedFolders[$watchId]) ;
                continue ;
            }
            $filePath = $watch['path'] . $event['name'] ;
            $accessed = $mask & IN_ACCESS ;
            $modified = $mask & IN_MODIFY ;
            $attrChange = $mask & IN_ATTRIB ;
            $closeWrite = $mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE ;
            $closeNowrite = $mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE ;
            $opened = $mask & IN_OPEN ;
            $movedTo = $mask & IN_MOVED_TO ;
            $movedFrom = $mask & IN_MOVED_FROM ;
            $created = $mask & IN_CREATE ;
            $deleted = $mask & IN_DELETE ;
            $deleteSelf = $mask & IN_DELETE_SELF ;
            $movedSelf = $mask & IN_MOVE_SELF ;
            $moved = $mask & IN_MOVE ;
            $unmount = $mask & IN_UNMOUNT ;
            $overflow = $mask & IN_Q_OVERFLOW ;
            $ignored = $mask & IN_IGNORED ;
            $isDir = $mask & IN_ISDIR ;
            $onlyDir = $mask & IN_ONLYDIR ;
            $dontFollow = $mask & IN_DONT_FOLLOW ;
            $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'iNotify alert (%08x) for file: %s:%s'
                                    , $mask
                                    , $filePath
                                    , ($accessed ? ' accessed' : '')
                                        . ($modified ? ' modified' : '')
                                        . ($attrChange ? ' attrChange' : '')
                                        . ($closeWrite ? ' closeWrite' : '')
                                        . ($closeNowrite ? ' closeNoWrite' : '')
                                        . ($opened ? ' opened' : '')
                                        . ($movedTo ? ' movedTo' : '')
                                        . ($movedFrom ? ' movedFrom' : '')
                                        . ($created ? ' created' : '')
                                        . ($deleted ? ' deleted' : '')
                                        . ($deleteSelf ? ' deleteSelf' : '')
                                        . ($movedSelf ? ' movedSelf' : '')
                                        . ($moved ? ' moved' : '')
                                        . ($unmount ? ' unmount' : '')
                                        . ($overflow ? ' overflow' : '')
                                        . ($ignored ? ' ignored' : '')
                                        . ($isDir ? ' isDir' : '')
                                        . ($onlyDir ? ' onlyDir' : '')
                                        . ($dontFollow ? ' dontFollow' : '')
                                        ] ) ;
            if ($overflow)
                $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Overflow has been indicated (%X).  Not much I can do about it, but I need to let you know.', $overflow ] ) ;
            if ($watchId == $watchMe) {
                // OK, our script has proably been chenged.  Before we do anything crazy, let's check the syntax.  If all is well,
                //     then we will submit a new process and end this one.
                if (checkSyntax($lov->pageFile())) { // Good to go.... let's let the new guy take over from here
                    $lov->writeLogLine( "Hey, that's me!  Better resubmit myself to start a new life!") ;
                    $cmd = sprintf('sleep 2 && nohup php %s %s >> %s 2>&1 &', escapeshellarg($lov->pageFile()), escapeshellarg($topFolder), escapeshellarg($lov->logNameOverride)) ;
                    $lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Command is %s', $cmd ] ) ;
                    $output = [] ;
                    exec($cmd, $output) ;
                    foreach($output as $line) {
                        if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0)
                            $lov->continueLogLine( $line) ;
                    }
                    break 2 ;
                } else { // Syntax errors in new script
                    $lov->writeLogLine( [ "That's me, but looks like there are syntax errors in the new file, so I'll just hang out here for a while." ] ) ;
                }
                continue ;
            } elseif ($deleteSelf) { // Deletion of a watched directory
                removeWatch($watchList, $watchId, REPORT_WATCH_COUNT, $mask) ;
                continue ;
            } elseif ($deleted)
                continue ; // Ignore file deletions (other than $deleteSelf, which we have already accommodated)
            elseif ($created && $isDir) { // If it's a new directory, we need only to add it to the watch list
                // Need to watch this folder
                $watch['events'] ++ ; // Record this event in the parent folder
                addWatch($watchList, $filePath) ; // Then add the child
                continue ;
            } elseif ($created || $closeWrite) {
                $watch['events'] ++ ;
                // This is where we check to see if it's a movie, etc, etc....
            }
        } // foreach
    } // while (true)
} // End of watchLoop
```

I ran the script with /svr/PlexMedia/Movies as its watch folder, and sure enough, about an hour after I added a couple of movies, they were deleted:

```
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/Passion of the Christ, The (1982).mp4: deleted
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000400) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/: deleteSelf
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Removing watch 690 (folder /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/) after 1 events triggered.
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: There are now 688 folders in the watch list (plus the self-monitor)
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Received event 00008000 for watch ID 690 but watchId is not in our watchedFolders array.
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (40000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982): deleted isDir
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002).mp4: deleted
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000400) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/: deleteSelf
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Removing watch 689 (folder /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/) after 1 events triggered.
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: There are now 687 folders in the watch list (plus the self-monitor)
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Received event 00008000 for watch ID 689 but watchId is not in our watchedFolders array.
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (40000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002): deleted isDir
2023-11-30 00:25:03 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/nohup.out: deleted
```

(I'd hoped that the time from the log would help me identify some process via syslog (I was thinking maybe it's something from cron; now I'm pretty sure it's not since thete's nothing unusual scheduled for 25 minutes after any hour.)

So my wish is to find a way to audit for these deletions.  I ran across auditd, which I have now installed, and started monitoring via the following command:

```
sudo auditctl -w /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/ -p rw -k var-run-pids
```

Then I created and deleted a file:
touch /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/me
rm /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/me

Sure enough, I got audit logs from the event.

```
----
time->Thu Nov 30 05:07:29 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701338849.085:1607): proctitle=746F756368002F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F6D65
type=PATH msg=audit(1701338849.085:1607): item=1 name="/svr/PlexMedia/Movies/me" inode=189727122 dev=08:01 mode=0100664 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1701338849.085:1607): item=0 name="/svr/PlexMedia/Movies/" inode=189726727 dev=08:01 mode=044777 ouid=997 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701338849.085:1607): cwd="/home/dennis"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701338849.085:1607): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffe6103cbb1 a2=941 a3=1b6 items=2 ppid=4936 pid=502375 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=6 comm="touch" exe="/usr/bin/touch" key="var-run-pids"
----
time->Thu Nov 30 05:07:32 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701338852.085:1608): proctitle=726D002F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F6D65
type=PATH msg=audit(1701338852.085:1608): item=1 name="/svr/PlexMedia/Movies/me" inode=189727122 dev=08:01 mode=0100664 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=DELETE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1701338852.085:1608): item=0 name="/svr/PlexMedia/Movies/" inode=189726727 dev=08:01 mode=044777 ouid=997 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701338852.085:1608): cwd="/home/dennis"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701338852.085:1608): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=557df82784d0 a2=0 a3=0 items=2 ppid=4936 pid=502383 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=6 comm="rm" exe="/usr/bin/rm" key="var-run-pids"
```

It's pretty easy o see from the above log that this was done by uid 1000 without setuid etc.  So I had some hope.

But when a real-world scenario occurred, the logs don't give me what I'd hoped for.  This is what my littls script reported:

```
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/Passion of the Christ, The (1982).mp4: deleted
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000400) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/: deleteSelf
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Removing watch 692 (folder /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982)/) after 1 events triggered.
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: There are now 688 folders in the watch list (plus the self-monitor)
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Received event 00008000 for watch ID 692 but watchId is not in our watchedFolders array.
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (40000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Passion of the Christ, The (1982): deleted isDir
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002).mp4: deleted
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (00000400) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/: deleteSelf
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Removing watch 691 (folder /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)/) after 1 events triggered.
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: There are now 687 folders in the watch list (plus the self-monitor)
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: Received event 00008000 for watch ID 691 but watchId is not in our watchedFolders array.
2023-11-30 08:25:06 /usr/local/bin/watchFolder: iNotify alert (40000200) for file: /svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002): deleted isDir
```

But the audit logs completely lacked any mention of this timeframe:

```
sudo ausearch -f "/svr/PlexMedia/Movies/Making Dark Side of the Moon (2002)"
[sudo] password for dennis:
----
time->Thu Nov 30 05:16:23 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701339383.653:4763): proctitle=66696E64002F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E20283230303229002D6C73
type=PATH msg=audit(1701339383.653:4763): item=0 name=2F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E20283230303229 inode=195952644 dev=08:01 mode=040775 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701339383.653:4763): cwd="/svr/plex-safeguard-against-deletion"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701339383.653:4763): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=4 a0=ffffff9c a1=55b159c93d40 a2=b0900 a3=0 items=1 ppid=431537 pid=504053 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts6 ses=549 comm="find" exe="/usr/bin/find" key="var-run-pids"
----
time->Thu Nov 30 08:03:05 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701349385.858:4983): proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572
type=PATH msg=audit(1701349385.858:4983): item=0 name=2F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E20283230303229 inode=195952644 dev=08:01 mode=040775 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701349385.858:4983): cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701349385.858:4983): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=59 a0=7f500d8b55b0 a1=98000 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=874 auid=4294967295 uid=997 gid=997 euid=997 suid=997 fsuid=997 egid=997 sgid=997 fsgid=997 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=506C6578204D656469612053657276 exe=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572 key="var-run-pids"
----
time->Thu Nov 30 08:03:05 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701349385.858:4984): proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572
type=PATH msg=audit(1701349385.858:4984): item=0 name=2F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E202832303032292F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E202832303032292E6D7034 inode=201326598 dev=08:01 mode=0100664 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701349385.858:4984): cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701349385.858:4984): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=59 a0=7f500f450b90 a1=88000 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=874 auid=4294967295 uid=997 gid=997 euid=997 suid=997 fsuid=997 egid=997 sgid=997 fsgid=997 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=506C6578204D656469612053657276 exe=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572 key="var-run-pids"
----
time->Thu Nov 30 08:03:27 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701349407.057:6549): proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572
type=PATH msg=audit(1701349407.057:6549): item=0 name=2F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E20283230303229 inode=195952644 dev=08:01 mode=040775 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701349407.057:6549): cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701349407.057:6549): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=68 a0=7f500f89af50 a1=98000 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=874 auid=4294967295 uid=997 gid=997 euid=997 suid=997 fsuid=997 egid=997 sgid=997 fsgid=997 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=506C6578204D656469612053657276 exe=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572 key="var-run-pids"
----
time->Thu Nov 30 08:03:27 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1701349407.057:6550): proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572
type=PATH msg=audit(1701349407.057:6550): item=0 name=2F7376722F506C65784D656469612F4D6F766965732F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E202832303032292F4D616B696E67204461726B2053696465206F6620746865204D6F6F6E202832303032292E6D7034 inode=201326598 dev=08:01 mode=0100664 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1701349407.057:6550): cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1701349407.057:6550): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=68 a0=7f500f450a90 a1=88000 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=874 auid=4294967295 uid=997 gid=997 euid=997 suid=997 fsuid=997 egid=997 sgid=997 fsgid=997 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=506C6578204D656469612053657276 exe=2F7573722F6C69622F706C65786D656469617365727665722F506C6578204D6564696120536572766572 key="var-run-pids"
```

Maybe auditd will do it for me, but my unfamiliarity with the tool prevents that... I don't know.  Before I go down some other rabbit hole I thought I might ask here if there's some magic way to find out what script or event is triggering the deletion of these files.  It seems very targeted - the library, as I implied, has been around for ages, and (best I can determine) the longstanding library is intact.  But it seems adamant about not having anything new added (or rather, not for very long indeed).

Any help?

Comment: If you know which files are going to be deleted, set perhaps their permissions to make them impossible to delete, then wait for errors to happen.

Comment: And if it's root who does the deletion?  And where would you propose I look for the errors?  About the only way I can think of to absolutely avoid deletion, is to mount the folder read-only, but then ... well, you know.  And there's still the problem of searching an entire, big system for an error messae that may even be thrown away.  I need a certain method.

Comment: By making changes to the script supplied in the question, I was able to determine that an rsync job was running at the time of the deletion, and from there I was able to locate the culprit. Remote system had delete-after specified on a synchronization process.   Rather than answering the question, though, this redoubles of the need for a solution, since the deletion didn't even originate on this system. It would've been nice to know upfront, that it was deleted by rsync. However, auditd doesn't seem to show anything useful. Again, this could easily be because I am unfamiliar with auditd.

Comment: This means that making the file undeletable would have found that the rsync has failed.

Comment: I looked into this further.  It would not have failed on the remote system.  The remote is set up expecting such permissions problems and therefore does not log the non-delete, and does not fail because of it.  It is silently ignored.

Comment: This doesn't look like a very healthy setup.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sure you're saying this because of your vast knowledge of the purpose and intent of the remote's vision.  Actually, it makes sense, and I'm not going to defend it.  What I will defend is the FACT that this question deserves a better answer and your comments are either missing or avoiding the point: We need to be able to determine conclusively what caused a file to be deleted on a system.